Dialogflow CX Cloud Function not deploying
I am trying to generate an answer to a question from flow A using a data store page in flow B. To do this, I will use a webhook. I got this code from Google's qwiklabs resources. However, I cant seem to get it to run. Here is my code:
import re
import json
import logging
from dfcx_scrapi.tools.webhook_util import WebhookUtil
from dfcx_scrapi.core.conversation import DialogflowConversation

# logging config
logging.basicConfig(
level=logging.INFO,
format='%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
DATA_STORE_PAGE = 'projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/LOCATION-ID/agents/AGENT-ID/flows/FLOW-ID/pages/PAGE-ID'

def get_session_id(req):
    """Get the current Session ID."""
    return req['sessionInfo']['session']
    
def call_data_store(user_query: str) -> str:
    """Calls Data Store route and retrieves response."""
    agent_id = '/'.join(DATA_STORE_PAGE.split('/')[:6])
    dc = DialogflowConversation(agent_id=agent_id)
    res = dc.reply(
    send_obj={'text': user_query},
    current_page=DATA_STORE_PAGE
    )
    return res

def _get_uri(sources: str) -> str:
    """Extracts the URI from the top returned source."""
    uri = None
    pattern = r'"uri":"(.*?)"'
    res = re.search(pattern, sources)
    if res:
        uri = res.group(1)
        uri = uri.replace("\\u003d", "=")
    return uri

def _get_title(sources: str) -> str:
    """Extracts the Title from the top returned source."""
    title = None
    pattern = r'"title":"(.*?)"'
    res = re.search(pattern, sources)
    if res:
        title = res.group(1)
    return title

def _get_snippet(sources: str) -> str:
    """Extracts the info card snippet from the top returned source."""
    snippet = None
    pattern = r'"snippet":"(.*?)"'
    res = re.search(pattern, sources)
    if res:
        snippet = res.group(1)
    return snippet

def main(request, debugging=False):
    """Main entrypoint"""
    logging.info('###### [cx_webhook] - CFX Triggered! ######')
    wu = WebhookUtil()
    if debugging:
        req = request
    else:
        req = request.get_json()
        logging.info('* [cx_webhook] Incoming Request: %s', req)
        webhook_tag = wu.get_tag(req)
    if webhook_tag == 'get_data_store_response':
        logging.info('* [cx_webhook] DATA STORE TAG RECEIVED.')
        text = wu.get_user_utterance(req)
        res = call_data_store(text)
        logging.info('* INFOBOT RESPONSE: %s', res)
        response_text = res['response_messages'][0]['text']
        response_params = res['params']
        title = _get_title(response_params['sources'])
        uri = _get_uri(response_params['sources'])
        snippet = _get_snippet(response_params['sources'])
        session_info = wu.build_session_info({"title": title, "uri": uri, "snippet": snippet})
        message = wu.build_response(response_text, session_info=session_info)
    else:
        logging.info('* [cx_webhook] No Webhook Tag Received.')
    res = json.dumps(message)
    logging.info(res)
    return res

My requirements.txt is below:
functions-framework==3.*
dfcx-scrapi

The error message:
Error message from Google Cloud
I tried allocating more memory into it, changing the Python version, as well as, adding packages in the requirements.txt but nothing seems to work.

Did you have a look at the deployment logs as mentioned in the error message? Usually this is about the entrypoint or a missing depency. If you just want to call Dialogflow, you can also do it directly using a flexible webhook and calling detectIntent. You may want to reuse the same session by using $request.session-id in the URL.

Try adding wheel and pandas in requirement.txt. This should solve the issue.

Is there any way to include sessionID in the query so that the context remains when the webhook is called again?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
